# conditional dataframe shift

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below dataframe

```
ID1 ID2 mon price
10  2   06  500
20  3   07  200
20  3   08  300
20  3   09  400
21  2   07  100
21  2   08  200
21  2   09  300
```

Required output :-

```
ID1 ID2 mon price   ID1_shift   ID2_shift   mon_shift   price_shift
10  2   06  500     10              2       06              500
20  3   07  200     20              3       07              200
20  3   08  300     20              3       07              200
20  3   09  400     20              3       08              300
21  2   07  100     21              2       07              100
21  3   08  200     21              2       07              100
21  4   09  300     21              3       08              200
```

I tried using df.shift() by different ways but was not successfull.

YOur valueable comments will be helpful.

I want to shift dataframe group by (ID1,ID2) and if NaN then fill with current values.

I tried below but it works with single column.

```
df["price_shift"]=df.groupby(["ID1","ID2"]).price.shift().fillna(df["price"])
```

Thanks

I came up with below , but this is feasible for less no of columns. Is there any way where complete row can be shifted with group by as above ?

```
df1['price_shift']=df.groupby(['ID1','ID2']).price.shift(1).fillna(df['price'])
df1['mon_shift']=df.groupby(['ID1','ID2']).mon.shift(1).fillna(df['mon'])

df1[['ID1_shift','ID2_shift']]=df[['ID1','ID2']]

df2=pd.concat([df, df1],axis=1)

df2
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you have tried so far, even if it hasn't worked for you?

Comment: It's also unclear what the logic is. What is the condition under which you want to shift your values?

Comment: code and explaination addded

Answer (score 0):

try the below:

```
for column_name in df.columns:
    df[column_name+"_shift"]=df[column_name]
```

cheers